# Why is the AVR GCC compiler using a full `CALL` even though I have set the `-mshort-calls` flag?

Tags: avr, gcc

I have set the `-mshort-calls` flag which is documented to replace the 4 byte long `CALL` instruction with the 2 byte long `RCALL` instruction when possible to save flash space and and cycles...

> -mshort-calls
>
> Assume that RJMP and RCALL can target the whole program memory.
>
> This option is used internally for multilib selection. It is not an
>   optimization option, and you don’t need to set it by hand.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html#index-mshort-calls

...and it set in Atmel Studio here...

[image]

Unfortunately the compiler is still using full `CALL` instructions even for a call that is only 2 bytes away...

```
    ...
    35f6:   0e 94 fd 1a     call    0x35fa  ; 0x35fa         
    35fa:   f8 94           cli
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This option was [removed in gcc 4.8](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1315031#comment-1315031) but not all the documentation was updated. Atmel Studio also still uses the obsolete flag.

The new option is called `-mrelax` on the compiler command line or `--relax` on the linker command line...

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/AVR-Options.html

After adding that flag, the above code compiled to...

```
...
3584:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x3586 
3586:   f8 94           cli
...
```

If you are using Atmel Studio, the new flag is misleadingly called "Relax Branches" and is located here...

[image]

In my case, enabling relative jumps and calls resulted in significant flash savings. If you are here because you also need to save flash space and/or cycles, I'd also recommend looking into enabling Link Time Optimization which also offers great savings at no cost.